# Controlling a Unity game from an Android device via bluetooth

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, remote-access

I have a functional Unity game on my PC. I just need to add one button that can be controlled from my Android phone via blue-tooth to carry out one of my defined functions when clicked. Please suggest me the simplest ways to go about it.